# Increment and re-execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my Javascript code `var x=1`. When some event occurred, `var x` will be incremented by 1. The updated `x` value will be used for some other  events. But the variable `x` value is always 1. It is because the Javascript code is compiled when the page is loaded. Now, how to use the updated value in the same page for other events?
Here is my code:

```
 var x=1;<br>
$(button).click(function(e){ <br>
         e.preventDefault();<br>
             x=x+1;   <br>        
     });<br>
//Now,when I would like to do some other event like..<br>

$("#newdiv"+x).click(function() {<br>
        alert("cliked");<br>
});<br>
```

I have some division with id="newdiv1" , id="newdiv2" and so on. How should differentiate the click on different divisions based on `x` value.

Comment: add the code, otherwise, it doesn't make sense what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event do `x=x+1;` or `x++`

Like this

```
var x=1; // x is initialized to 1;
....someEvent(){
   x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code?

```
$("#newdiv"+x).click(function() {
alert("cliked");
});
```

The issue here is that you're just using "x" to identify a div but then the function attached is generic. If you'd like to find out which div was clicked then use something like this:

```
$("#newdiv"+x).click(function(event) {
var source = event.target || event.srcElement;
console.log(source);
alert($(this).attr("id"));
};
```